# Segment Declaration Name Rejected in ML64 (for Windows x64)

Tags: windows-10, x86-64, windows-7-x64

I am porting a major 32-bit Assembler project from WIN32 to WIN64. The codebase stretches back 29 years (and I wrote the lot, so I do understand it!). I am trying to change as little as possible, to help maintain separate 32-bit and 64-bit versions for some good time into the future.

One little thing just bothers me: segment declarations. For some reason, ML64 accepts this:

***data segment para 'data'***

but not this:

***code segment para 'code'***

If I use other names than "code" (eg, "kode"), it works. So I guess I have my solution, but just out of curiosity, does anyone know why a name which worked fine in ML.EXE (32-bit) is being spat out by ML64?

Brian

Answer (score -1):

IIRC Microsoft gave up on maintaining ML64.exe, because they tried to push the `.NET` paradigm.

This info has been leaked as a rumor to the [MASMForum (only general link, no specific one)](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php) by Hutch. **So the probability that it is a real bug is *HIGH*.**

As an alternative you can try [JWASM](https://github.com/JWasm/JWasm) and see if it also emits an error on the same code, because it claims to be *MASM compatible*.